# Resetting the slider handles in HorizontalRangeSlider in DOJO

Tags: javascript, dojo, rangeslider

I have created the **HorizontalRangeSlider** like this,

```
    this.horizontalSlider = new HorizontalRangeSlider({
            name : "slider",
            //To place the slider handles at min max.
            value : [10,100],
            minimum : 10,
            maximum : 100,
            intermediateChanges : false,
            showButtons : false,
            onChange : //onChange call method.
        }, this.slider);
        this.horizontalSlider.startup();

        this.horizontalSliderRule = new HorizontalRule({
            container : "topDecoration",
            style:"height:5px",
            count : 2,              
            numericMargin: 1
        }, this.sliderRule);
        this.horizontalSliderRule.startup();
```

Then after changing the position of the slider handles now i want to reset the position of the slider handles programmatically, for this i am doing like this

```
this.horizontalSlider.value=[10,100];
```

But this is not affecting anything in the slider.How to reset the position of the slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply setting the values by way of using "=" of the RangeSlider won't trigger the code in the slider to update. For most dojo elements, I'd recommend using the below method:

```
this.horizontalSlider.set("value",[10,100]);
```

Here's a fiddle with it working: http://jsfiddle.net/g4s05og0/

Comment: @ Richard It's not refreshing the handles position

Comment: @ManjunathM I'm not sure why your code isn't working. I've edited my answer to include an example of it working. Can you include maybe a fiddle of your code not working?